# Quantities having unit but no dimension

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

1. Can there be such a quantity which has units but not dimension?

In case of gravitational constant for instance, it's also just a number, then it has units, but suppose to be dimension less because it's a constant number.

2. Also what does this physically mean?

[**please try to clarify what things are suppose to have units and dimensions**]

Comment: See [the Wikipedia article on dimensionless constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant)

Comment: Unfortunately, that possible duplicate doesn't quite answer that question, or this one, for that matter. The key problem is one of semantics rather than physics. The word "dimension" has multiple meanings. One meaning addresses the concept of degrees of freedom. Another very distinct meaning is addresses the concept of different kinds of physical qualities.

Comment: @DavidHammen thanks. Now no one will be answering my question since they closed it?!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but there are derived units in the International System of Units (SI) which are defined as synonyms of 1 and, thus, quantities of those kinds can be expressed with units, but they are actually dimensionless (or with dimension 1, as one can also say).

Two such examples are the *radian* and the *steradian*: these are derived units which are equal to 1 (see the [SI brochure, section 2.2, table 3](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section2-2.html)).

Thus, for an angle $\theta$, you can write

$$\theta = 3.14\,\mathrm{rad},$$

but $\theta$ is actually a dimensionless quantity, that is, $\theta = 3.14\,\mathrm{rad} = 3.14$.

*Why do we keep such redundancy?*

Mainly for historical reasons, but many people like also to use certain specific units to highlight the kind of quantity where confusion may arise (e.g., when discussing frequency and angular frequency).